# Model.objects.get() works, but not when using a ForeignKey attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a profile model that looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

Here's my template

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'profile' u=i.user %}" class='username_foreign'>{{ i.user }}</a></h3>
```

which points to this url:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<u>\w+)/', profile, name='profile')
```

and here's my view function:

```
def profile(request, u):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        profile = Profile.objects.get(username=u)

    return render(request, 'base.html', {})
```

As you can see here I pass through `u` which is the username. But when I try to `get()` the `profile` via the `username` passed through, I get this error:

```
ValueError at /profile/zorgan/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'zorgan'
```

However when I use `get()` on any other attribute of my `Profile` model, it works fine. And it even prints my `username`. So when I do this:

```
def profile(request, u):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print(u) #prints username
        profile = Profile.objects.get(points=50)
        print(profile.username) #successfully prints username (same as 'u')

    return render(request, 'base.html', {})
```

As you can see above, getting the `Profile` object via its attribute doesn't work for `username`. And the problem isn't related to the `u` as that successfully prints aswell. Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field you've called `username` isn't a username at all. It's a ForeignKey, which is an integer value pointing at a row in another table. You should call it what it is: `user`.

To look up the actual username, in the User table, you need to use the double-underscore syntax. This would work:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(username__username=u)
```

but as I said, you should really rename that `username` field, in which case you would do:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user__username=u)
```

Another way to do it would be to look up the User directly and then get the Profile:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=u)
profile = user.profile
```

but this takes two separate queries, rather than one joined one.

Comment: Thankyou very much that solves the problem. I'm not too familiar with the double __ syntax so can you give a quick summary or point me somewhere that explains it? Why is it used for ForeignKey fields and not the others?

Comment: Because the username value is *in another model*, ie User.